# I want to make a css style invalid, but don't want to set that style to any value

Tags: html, css

In this file (.../css/screen.css), it has some code like this:

```
.field-group { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin: 6px 0;
}
```

But I don't want width:100%, and I don't want to set width to any value
So, I wrote it like this,

```
<style>
    .field-group { 
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
</style>
```

But it doesn't work, the width style is still 100%.
Please help me!

Comment: You want to make it *invalid*?  Or you simply want to *unset* it?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.field-group { 
    margin: 6px 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Auto is the default value of width.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to accept this answer as correct when you are able to.

Comment: @BelieBetray also note, since margin is the same value, you don't need to write it twice. you only need to write the property if you intend to overwrite it. this helps keep the code cleaner